# making "ssh localhost 'sleep 10'" launch command in background

Tags: bash, ssh, tty, nohup, pty

`ssh localhost 'sleep 10'` takes 10s to run so I was thinking what if I used `nohup` and `&`. Unfortunately, that didn't make a difference.

`bash -c "nohup sleep 10 2> /dev/null &"` returns immediately so I tried `ssh localhost 'nohup sleep 10 2> /dev/null &'`but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ssh localhost exit`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Cyrus - I'm trying to run a time consuming command. Maybe I'm trying to write a script that'll restore a large MySQL DB, which could takes hours. Or maybe I'm trying to run Jack the Ripper or something. Either way, for the purposes of simulating a time consuming script, `sleep x` suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nohup to work as you expect you also need to redirect *stdout*:

```
ssh localhost 'nohup sleep 10 > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
# OR
ssh localhost 'nohup sleep 10 >& /dev/null &'
```